# Quando a validação dos campos é acionada, os dropdownlists não carregam no Asp.net core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quando eu inicio uma tela de cadastro, o sistema carrega uma `ViewModel` com os `combobox` carregados:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu, por exemplo, clicar no botão gravar, os campos da minha viewmodel são validadados, só que a página não mantém os combobox carregados.

Como resolver isso?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class PessoaFisicaViewModel
{
        [DisplayName("Código")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Campo obrigatório")]
        [DisplayName("Nome Completo")]
        public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Apelido")]
        public string Apelido { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Data em formato inválido")]
        [DisplayName("Nascimento")]
        public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Sexo")]
        public Sexo Sexo { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Sexo")]
        public string SexoDescricao { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Sexos")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Sexos { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Estado Civil")]
        public EstadoCivil EstadoCivil { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Estado Civil")]
        public string EstadoCivilDescricao { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Estados Civis")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EstadosCivis { get; set; }

}
```

---

```
@model SistemaComercial.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PessoaFisica";
}

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.NomeCompleto" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.NomeCompleto" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.NomeCompleto" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Apelido" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Apelido" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Apelido" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.DataNascimento" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.DataNascimento" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.DataNascimento" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Sexo" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Sexo" asp-items="Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.Sexos" class="form-control">
                <option value="">--Selecione--</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Sexo" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadoCivil" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadoCivil" asp-items="Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadosCivis" class="form-control">
                <option value="">--Selecione--</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadoCivil" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Policy = "CanWriteCustomerData")]
        [Route("pessoa-gerenciamento/cadastrar-novo")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(pessoaViewModel);
            _pessoaAppService.Register(pessoaViewModel);

            if (IsValidOperation())
                ViewBag.Sucesso = "Pessoa Cadastrada!";

            return View(pessoaViewModel);
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o controller!?

Comment: Acabei de atualizar com o controller.. :)

Comment: Quando você clica no "gravar" é chamado o método _post_ do seu _controller_; você precisa retornar o objeto `pessoa` (ou seja lá qual o usado) para que seja recarregado em caso de erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analise bem o seu código, acabei reparando que o objeto passado é um `PessoaFisicaViewModel`, e a View é assinada como `PessoaViewModel`, aparentemente a `PessoaViewModel` não possui as propriedades da listagem de combobox (os ICollection), por isso ao ser submitidos, a conversão de `PessoaFisicaViewModel` para `PessoaViewModel` faz com que estas propriedades sejam perdidas.

Comment: Mas aí é que tá.... O Combobox Natureza está na PessoaViewModel e não deveria dar esse problema... Algo me diz que o problema esteja nos bindings.. ex: <select asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadoCivil" asp-items="Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadosCivis" class="form-control">
                <option value="">--Selecione--</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadoCivil" class="text-danger"></span>

Comment: É curioso, a propriedade <code>EstadosCivis</code>, de acordo com a View, não está em <code>PessoaViewModel</code> e sim em uma propriedade da <code>PessoaViewModel</code>, chamada <code>PessoaFisicaViewModel</code>.

Comment: Exatamente.... Ela faz parte de PessoaFisicaViewModel. Quando eu Carrego a PessoaViewModel, ela já vem carregada tb.

Comment: @JalberRomano, nossa, agora realmente entendi toda a arquitetura. Você já experimentou renomear o objeto recebido no Controller, para um nome que não seja exatamente o mesmo da classe do objeto, como apenas "pessoa"?

Comment: Tentei.... Continua sem funcionar...

Comment: Descobri o problema: Na minha Create.cshtml faltou o trecho @section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}

Comment: Isso causava o problema.. afff

Comment: Obrigado a todos que tentaram me ajudar!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso, tenho a impressão de que você seleciona os valores nos Combos envia para SUBMIT, porém como nada ainda foi salvo, a validação é feita mas o objeto é retornado novamente pelo `_pessoaAppService.GetJoinById()` e neste caso, os valores do Combo não existem no objeto retornado por este serviço, e por isso não retornam populados.

No meu entendimento, o que você deve fazer é, na validação, retornar o objeto validado e não substituir pelo objeto retornado pelo `_pessoaAppService.GetJoinById()`.

Comment: Eu havia postado a Action errada (Edit)... Eu corrigi... A action correta é a Create. Acho que estou errando no cshtml.... POis na Actions os comboobx chegam com Null (Conforme imagem)...

Comment: @JalberRomano, você precisa utilizar esta abordagem? Você não acha mais interessante remover a listagem do objeto ViewModel e colocar apenas no ViewData? Assim você consegue manipular com mais controle, nos métodos do Controller.

Comment: Pois é @E.Leal... Já vi modelos na net que funcionam como o meu tendo uma propriedade viewModel de pessoaFisica dentro da minha viewModel de Pessoa... Quando eu faço o submit, ele parece estar jogando null para as propriedades IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Comment: @JalberRomano quanto a isso não vejo problema, o que acho pouco comum é popular a listagem do combobox no objeto viewModel. Tenho a impressão de que estes IColletion são atributos que não são passados pelo SUBMIT, por isto ficam nulos.

Comment: Eles são populados na minha PessoaAppService... Quando eu crio uma nova ViewModel ele faz o carregamento lá e devolve uma viewmodel com os combobox carregados. O Problema é que o Submit não está dando o Post com eles carregados... ele acaba "setando" com null.