# Problemas ao dar Post em uma ViewModel para o Controller - Asp.Net Core 2 MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma ViewModel que utilizo para carregar dados de uma pessoa física ou jurídica. Ela contém algumas propriedades como PessoasNaturezas, dentre outras, que eu utilizo para carregar meus dropdownlists da minha view. O Problema está justamente entre minha view e meu método Create da minha Controller. Quando eu dou um Post, as propriedades da minha viewmodel ficam com NULL... Parece que, ao dar o Post, o sistema limpa e seta as propriedades que são do tipo IEnumerable para null. Como resolver isso????

OBS: Já postei um assunto parecido, mas o problema era na view Create quando eu criava uma viewmodel em branco. Eu não havia inserido um bloco de script javascript.. Por favor, **desconsiderem aquele post**, pois este é relacionado ao salvamento e está mais detalhado.
[Quando a validação dos campos é acionada, os dropdownlists não carregam no Asp.net core MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280566/quando-a-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-dos-campos-%C3%A9-acionada-os-dropdownlists-n%C3%A3o-carregam-no-asp-n/280681?noredirect=1#comment573394_280681)

```js
 public class PessoaViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Código")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Natureza")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Escolha uma Natureza")]
        public PessoaNatureza PessoaNatureza { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Natureza")]
        public string PessoaNaturezaDescricao { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Naturezas")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PessoasNaturezas { get; set; }

        public PessoaFisicaViewModel PessoaFisicaViewModel { get; set; }
        public PessoaJuridicaViewModel PessoaJuridicaViewModel { get; set; }
    }
```

```js
@model SistemaComercial.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PessoaFisica";
}

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.NomeCompleto" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.NomeCompleto" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.NomeCompleto" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Apelido" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Apelido" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Apelido" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.DataNascimento" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.DataNascimento" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.DataNascimento" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Sexo" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Sexo" asp-items="Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.Sexos" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-- SELECIONE --</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Sexo" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadoCivil" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadoCivil" asp-items="Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadosCivis" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-- SELECIONE --</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadoCivil" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

```js
@using SistemaComercial.Domain.ValueObjects
@model SistemaComercial.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cadastrar Nova Pessoa";
}
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title">Cadastrar nova Pessoa</h2>
    </div>
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div class="panel-body container-fluid">
            @* Replacing classic Validation Summary to Custom ViewComponent as TagHelper *@
            <vc:summary />
            <!-- Example Tabs -->
            <div class="example-wrap">
                <div class="nav-tabs-horizontal">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-plugin="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="active" role="presentation">
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsOne" aria-controls="exampleTabsOne"
                               role="tab">Dados Pessoais</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsTwo" aria-controls="exampleTabsTwo"
                               role="tab">Documentos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsThree" aria-controls="exampleTabsThree"
                               role="tab">Endereços</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsFour" aria-controls="exampleTabsFour"
                               role="tab">Contatos</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content padding-top-20">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="exampleTabsOne" role="tabpanel">
                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="Id" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="PessoaNatureza" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <select asp-for="PessoaNatureza" asp-items="Model.PessoasNaturezas" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">--SELECIONE--</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <span asp-validation-for="PessoaNatureza" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                @if (Model.PessoaNatureza == PessoaNatureza.Fisica)
                                {
                                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_PessoaFisica")
                                }
                                else if (Model.PessoaNatureza == PessoaNatureza.Juridica)
                                {
                                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_PessoaJuridica")
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_PessoaFisica")
                                }

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="exampleTabsTwo" role="tabpanel">

                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="exampleTabsThree" role="tabpanel">

                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="exampleTabsFour" role="tabpanel">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Example Tabs -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    @*<input type="submit" value="Gravar" class="btn btn-success" />
                        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-info">Voltar à Lista</a>*@

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon wb-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Gravar</button>

                    <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-danger">
                        <span title="Retornar à Lista" class="icon wb-arrow-left"></span> Retornar à lista
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

```js
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Policy = "CanWriteCustomerData")]
        [Route("pessoa-gerenciamento/cadastrar-novo")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(pessoaViewModel);
            _pessoaAppService.RegisterPessoaFisica(pessoaViewModel);

            if (IsValidOperation())
                ViewBag.Sucesso = "Pessoa Cadastrada!";

            return View(pessoaViewModel);
        }
```

```js
@model SistemaComercial.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PessoaJuridica";
}

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaJuridicaViewModel.RazaoSocial" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input asp-for="PessoaJuridicaViewModel.RazaoSocial" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaJuridicaViewModel.RazaoSocial" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaJuridicaViewModel.NomeFantasia" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input asp-for="PessoaJuridicaViewModel.NomeFantasia" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaJuridicaViewModel.NomeFantasia" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PessoaJuridicaViewModel.DataAbertura" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input asp-for="PessoaJuridicaViewModel.DataAbertura" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaJuridicaViewModel.DataAbertura" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode colocar o código da PartialView onde estão os combos?

Comment: Atualizei a postagem @Ricardo Pontual...

Comment: Você está usando asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.Sexo" porém pela imagem que colocou, a propriedade que está null se chama "Sexos". Já verificou isto?

Comment: Aí me bateu a dúvida: Eu tenho duas propriedades na minha viewmodel: public Sexo Sexo {get; set;} e public iEnumerable<SelectListItem> Sexo {get; set;}... Uma uso para Label e a aoutra para o Dropdownlist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você posta a `Model`, só será postado o que foi associado aos elementos na `View` com nomes correspondentes às propriedades da sua `Model`.

No código abaixo:

```
<select asp-for="PessoaNatureza" asp-items="Model.PessoasNaturezas" class="form-control">
    <option value="">--SELECIONE--</option>
</select>
```

Quem está associado ao `select` é **PessoaNatureza**, e somente ele será postado, **Model.PessoasNaturezas** apenas foi utilizado para montar o `select` e não está associado a campo algum, por isso não será postado, dai chega vazio.

Nesses casos, você precisa carregar novamente essas listas no seu método **Create** antes de retornar para a `View`. Uma solução é fazer isso no construtor da sua `Model`. Outra solução, bem pior, seria armazenar **Model.PessoasNaturezas** num campo escondido, por exemplo `<input type='hidden' name='Model.PessoasNaturezas' />`

Comment: @Ricado Pontual muito obrigado pela dica!!! Funcionou 100% Criei um construtor para a viewmodel e "setei" os carregamentos...  public PessoaViewModel()
        {
            PessoasNaturezas = ExtensaoDeEnumerador.EnumParaSelectListGenerico<PessoaNatureza>("U", PessoaNatureza.ToString()).OrderBy(x => x.Text);
        }